# Set search textbox above datagridviewcolomns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview, above this datagridview I set a flowlayoutpanel where I want to add some textbox programmaticly where the user can type in some searchterms.

I take the size of the column from the datagrid:

```
int size = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
```

and gif the textbox the same size:

```
TextBox box = new TextBox();
box.Width = size - 1;
```

But the size of the textbox mismatch the columnsize. 
And I don't see what goes wrong

Code:

```
public partial class DataTableFormSearch : Form
{
    public DataTableFormSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = createTable();
        fillPanelWithSearch();
    }

    public DataTable createTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("TestCol1", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("TestCol2", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("TestCol3", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("TestCol4", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("TestCol5", typeof(String));

        return dt;
    }

    public void fillPanelWithSearch()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {

            TextBox box = new TextBox();
            box.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(box);
        }
        resizeControls();
    }

    public void resizeControls()
    {
        if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                int size = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;

                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Width = size;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DataTableFormSearch_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resizeControls();
    }
}
```

when the event of SizeChanged is triggerd the boxes change to the correct size, but not when the dialog pop-up

Comment: The colomns are the same size, so it doesn't matter of i is the right colomn at this moment.

Comment: Nop, in your way the Textboxes should be larger than the datagridview, but they are not (because I not have the rights to add image, I saved it here): http://imageshack.com/a/img28/2853/hek0.png

But I have made a change, to my program so when it resize the boxes grow larger and smaller, and when I change the window the boxes are all set above the correct column so the code works. *Edited the code above*

Comment: Are you calling that method in the constructor?  If so, don't.  Use the OnLoad() override method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your method to the OnLoad override because the DataGrdiView control and it's columns haven't been properly sized yet during the constructor:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);
  fillPanelWithSearch();
}
```